# Получить значения словаря в генераторе

Tags: python-3.x, json, request

```
def with_gen(): 
    req = request.urlopen('https://www.marvel.com/v1/pagination/grid_cards?entityType=character&limit=3000&sortField=title&sortDirection=asc&title=')
    js_req = (item for item in json.loads(req.read()))
    for item in js_req: 
        print(js_req[item])
```

Я получаю текстовый файл и (ради эксперимента) решил сделать словарь из JSON'a этого файла, но обнаружил, что не могу обратиться к значениям по ключу во время итерации и получаю ошибку:

```
TypeError: 'generator' object is not subscriptable
```

Хотя простой пробег циклом по `js_req` работает, но выводит ключи. Но если исп. метод `.values()` - падает ошибка

```
for item in js_req.values(): 
        print(item)

AttributeError: 'generator' object has no attribute 'values'
```

Как получить значения при таком варианте? И возможно ли вообще это?

P.S. Это работает, но выводит ключи. А мне нужны значения

```
js_req = (item for item in json.loads(req.read()))
    for item in js_req: 
        print(item) 

code
status
etag
age
cache
data
```

Comment: Замените `print(js_req[item])` на `print(item)`

Comment: @insolor, в таком случае итерация идёт по ключам, а мне нужны значения

Comment: Ну вы в генератор собрали только ключи. Чтобы и значения были, нужно брать items() или values() от json.loads(req.read()). P.S. да, абсолютно не понятно, зачем тут вообще генератор.

Comment: а зачем генератор? нельзя просто `js_req = json.loads(req.read())`?

Comment: @Danis, можно, у меня так и работает. Просто я решил ради интереса проверить

Comment: @insolor, точно, спасибо. Ваш вариант помог)